# Syntax error with multiple declarations in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    float arr[25];
    int i;
    double x;
    int a, b, c, e, f;
    double y = a * pow(x, 2) + b * x + c;

    printf("a: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);

    printf("b: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &b);

    printf("c: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &c);

    printf("e: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &e);

    printf("f: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &f);

    double interval = (f - e) / 25.0 ;

    for (int i = 0, double x = e; i < 25; i++, x += interval)
    {
        printf("%f", y);
        x++;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

I get **[Error] expected identifier or '(' before 'double'**. How can i fix it? It doesnt seem like i really need to change something in

```
for (int i = 0, double x = e; i < 25; i++, x += interval)
```

or maybe im wrong and dont know how to write multiple conditions.

Comment: Are you intentionally doing `x++` _and_ `x += interval` in your iteration? Also, your iteration could be rewritten as simple arithmetic.. because `y` doesn’t change value, you’ll get the same number 25 times.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can't do that.

By the way, those are declarations, not conditions. Only the middle part of a `for` loop is a condition.

You can declare multiple variables in the first part of a `for` loop, but only if they have the same base type (e.g. `int`):

```
for (int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3; ...; ...)
```

The workaround in your case is to declare at least one of the variables outside of the loop:

```
{  // this outer block limits the scope of x
    double x = e;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++, x += interval) 
    {
        printf("%f", y);
        x++;
    }
}
```

That said, your code doesn't really make sense. Your loop doesn't use `x`, so there's no point in setting it. On the other hand, the value you're printing 25 times (`y`) doesn't change in the loop. It's set at the top of your main function, computed from a different `x` variable that is uninitialized.

You should move the declaration and initialization of `y` into the loop and delete the outer `x`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53238897/1848654.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define variables with multiple types with the comma:

```
for(int i = 0, double x...
```

Instead:

```
x = e;
for (int i = 0; i<...
```

and the `x` is already defined above.

Answer (score 1):

You could embedded them into a struct. I do not recommend it because IMO it is not a good coding practice as it is not easy to understand (at first sight)…

```
typedef struct {int i; double x;} S;
for (S yourStruct = {0,e}; yourStruct.i < 25 ; yourStruct.i++, yourStruct.x += interval)
{
    printf("%f", y);
    yourStruct.x++;
}
```

Comment: Clang objects to this with “declaration of non-local variable in 'for' loop”. I am looking for something in the C standard that governs it.

Comment: You can declare a structure object in the `for` loop; clang does not object to `for (S yourStruct = {0, e};…)`, where `S` is a previously defined type. It is only the declaration of the structure type within the `for` that it objects to.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Correct me if I'm wrong, but within for loop, one should be able to use *any* declaration/definition one could use outside as well. So if `void f(void) { struct { int x; } s; }` is legal, one should be able to do the same in the for loop. So I conclude clang is wrong in rejecting it...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Clang is generally pretty good, but I have not found a constraint in the C standard that this violates. I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468223/declare-structure-within-for) to see if anybody else can resolve it.

Comment: What is happening here is that Clang believes the declaration of the structure type within the `for` violates C 2018 (and same in 1999) 6.8.5 3: “The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class
`auto` or `register`.” Since the declaration declares a type (6.7.2.1 8 in C 2018, paragraph 7 in C 1999: “The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type…”), it is not true that the declaration part of this `for` only declares identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

Comment: FYI, I [answered my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53566875/298225). I have concluded the likely intent was in fact to prohibit declaring anything other than identifiers for automatic or register objects in `for` statement, although the exclusion of declaring a structure type in the course of that may have been inadvertent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a matter of the for loop:

```
void f(void)
{
    int x, y; // legal - and you can do the same in a for loop's initialization section
    int z, double d; // can't do that either, even outside for loop...
};
```

All variables that you declare in a single expression need to have the same (base!) type, be it within for loop, function body or global. *'Base type'*: Well, because you legally can do stuff like `int x, *p;`, with `x` and `p` being of different type, but base/underlying type in both cases is `int`.